# One Contribution page with multiple webforms

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm

Has anyone had any issues with using one contribution page from CIVI together with multiple webforms.

For example - One webform processing annual memberships, another processing life memberships but using the same contribution page.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might want to consider is that the webform uses the receipt language configured on the contribution page you're using, so you might check to confirm that the verbiage is sufficiently generic to cover both types of membership.

Lesley

Answer (score 1):

No problem! Once you indicate you want Membership signup in your Webform -> CiviCRM tab the Element Membership Type that is then created in your Webform tab is fully configurable [hit Static Options] as to which of the Membership Types are to be shown on any given Webform CiviCRM integration. Just check off the ones you want on any given Webform.

Answer (score 0):

It should be alright - contribution page is used for picking up all the memebership and payment instrument from CiviCRM

You shouldn't be get any issue at all

I guess this helps !!!